# Zoom to search (marker) position Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I would like my map to zoom to the search (marker) position, when i search an address.
I have been looking through the forum and found advice but I cant get it to work.

Code sample

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {lat: 52.0, lng: 1.0}
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }

  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        map.setZoom(14);
        map.panTo(Marker.position);

      } 
      else {
        alert('clever text here: ' + status);
      }
    });
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: First: Welcome to Stackoverflow. 
Its a bit unclear what exactly did not work here. Could be please be more specific what exactly the problem is? "Dont work" is not helpful :-).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean "I can't get it to work"? Please, spend a few words on your exact problem, this will also help you to understand the situation better.

Comment: Thank very much for your response. OK I see. English is not my first language, but I will do my best to explain. Everything else works fine. I search an address and it pans to the location, and centers the marker, but it keeps the zoom level from InitMap (10) I would like it to Zoom to (14) so I put in the map.setZoom(14) hoping it wold zoom to the search result.

Answer (score 0):

The setZoom(14) inside the geocodeAddress() function is not working since you have called it from an incorrect map object reference. You should call **resultsMap.setZoom(14)** instead of map.setZoom(14).

The `"map"` variable is declared inside the function initMap() and is passed as an argument when the geocodeAddress() function is called: `geocodeAddress(geocoder, map)`.

Now in the method definition of geocodeAddress(), the map object reference is changed to **`"resultsMap"`** parameter name: `function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap){...}`. This is why you'll have to use **`resultsMap.setZoom(14)`** inside the geocodeAddress() function.

Here's a working sample in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxmnjL6s/3/).

Hope this helps!